# Set Page Scroll to show content if Fixed div overflows

Tags: html, css

HTML5 is awesome! Bit to learn with formatting for a novice like me however.

I have a layout page in MVC4 and it is using two fixed div's. One is a menu and so on and the other is a content holder.

My css snipit:

```
.maincontent
{
position: fixed;

top:7px;
left:382px;
right:7px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

I want to auto scroll the page if this div overflows. I have tried:

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

in both the body css and maincontent css elements but its not working.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure, that your contents are actually high enough. One of the best ways to "debug" malfunctioning CSS is to use the `Inspect this Element` funtion in chrome/safari/firefox etc. Just click on one of your elements with the right mouse button

Comment: So using overflow-y is supposed to work then? Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I tried failed.

Quick and dirty, I put the div's inside a table, single row, dual column, and set the second div to:

```
position:relative;
```

Quick and dirty table:

```
<table class="contenttbl">
<tr>
<td><div class="div1"></div></td>
<td><div class="div2"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

With div1 CSS:

```
.div1
{
position: fixed;
top:3px;
right:auto;
width: 355px;
height: auto;
}
```

and div2 CSS:

```
.div2
{
position: relative;
margin-left:7px;
margin-right:7px;
margin-bottom:7px;
width:inherit;
}
```

It works this way exactly as I need but I would like to know if there is a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: hidden;` instead of `auto`

Comment: No, doesn't work, tried both in the div container and body elements.